# В solution постоянно лочится папка Properties

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Приветствую!

Пожалуйста, подскажите как исправить проблему с постоянным lock-ом папки properties в solution vs 2017?  Check In и Check out не изменяют статус папки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вам это так важно?

Comment: Я заметил что в какой-то момент файл внутри папок перестают обновляться. Причем по аналогии начинают также лочиться не только эти папки, но и другие. В VS 2015 таких проблем не замечал

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. В Source Control Explorer для проблемной папки необходимо сделать Lock и только после этой операции нормально работает Check Out.

[image: Как сделать Lock папки]